# Amazon MWS API (Product and real time order update)

Tags: api, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-mws, amazon-product-api

1) Product - API calls
I am trying to import all my listing data in my local website, but I could not find proper API to get all product related information from 1 api call.
 
- Product images 
- Product variations 
- Product attributes

Currently I am using "_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_' report and GetMatchingProductRequest to achieve that but not get all information which I can see on Amazon selling website.. Can anyone suggest is there any proper API to do so?

2) Real time Order/Product Updates - When any new order came in my amazon selling account I like to received real time order update to my given webservice URL. is that possible in Amazon? I have read spec but not find any relavant information to achieve that..
Can anyone please suggest is that possible in Amazon MWS api?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Amazon Product Advertising API to get product's Images,Rank,Sales Rank etc. [Link](http://associates-amazon.s3.amazonaws.com/scratchpad/index.html)

And also to get order status update you can use Amazon MWS Subscriptions API [Link](https://developer.amazonservices.co.uk/gp/mws/api.html?ie=UTF8&group=subscriptions&section=subscriptions&version=latest)

I hope these helps you.

Comment: Hi keyur do you know how to give webservice URL in that? I found only SQS.. can it post data for all new orders and product changes to my given https URL?

Comment: Hi Jigar I haven't use this Subscription API before, But if you use this scratch pad it might give you an idea. https://mws.amazonservices.co.uk/scratchpad/index.html